# How can I build an MoS2 nanoribbon?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, materials-design

Are there any codes available? What is the easiest way?

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements? What exactly qualifies as a nanoribbon? There are a number of software packages that can generate periodic structures from a unit cell. Does the software need to be free and/or open source or are you willing to purchase a commercial product?

Comment: If you just want the structure with xyz file, I suggest vesta

Comment: @sslucifer why not expand on that and write it as an answer? It would be nice for us to clear up our unanswered queue a bit and [get back to 90% answered](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/matter-modeling)!

Comment: Read the answer of this previous [post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6765/4232). You can define regions within [lammps](https://www.lammps.org/) for different shapes and even perform boolean operations on those regions to obtain finer control. I'll provide a sample script if needed.

Answer (score 4):

### NANOCUT

What is Nanocut?

> Nanocut is a program designed to cut out various objects from three
> dimensional crystal structures. It is aimed to be helpful when
> creating geometry input for atomistic simulations. Currently it can
> create following objects:
>
> - Spherical cluster
> - Polyhedral cluster
> - Cylindrical cluster
> - Spherical wire (1D periodic)
> - Polyhedral wire (1D periodic)
> - Plain slab (2D periodic)
> - Supercells (3D periodic)

The manual of NANOCUT can be seeing [here](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/nanocut/downloads/manual-12.12.pdf).
The repository is [here](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/nanocut/src/master/).
The program can be downloaded [here](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/nanocut/downloads/nanocut-12.12.tar.gz).